# trigger google web app with google script function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

For about a week or so I am unsuccessfully trying to find a solution to trigger my google web app with some google script function from all available forums and sites that world wide web has to offer.

The Google Web Apps documentation says: 
"When a program sends the app an HTTP GET request, Apps Script runs the function doGet(e)"

So, I am trying to trigger my web app
(deployed as webb app, executed as me and anyone, even anonymous has access):

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
}
```

by sending http get request with:

`function openTab() {
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzWKeDgj6DhLsdkeHYWsWRqHbyOa4CnHjHa-rK17hgRxWF0eont/exec"); }`

I tried also with ' instead of "

But it just won't trigger my doGet function :(

By saying won't trigger I mean that I expect the same result as clicking on the my web app link:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzWKeDgj6DhLsdkeHYWsWRqHbyOa4CnHjHa-rK17hgRxWF0eont/exec

that opens a new tab in the browser and outputs: Hello, world! or shows promp for user respons like:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxQxXgRX6DyrGDyf-G0BkCts5Ty2VpgG4UTAYwcB7ejFF24Ixui/exec

I managed to find something that works, but only on deskTop :(

```
function openTab() {

var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxQxXgRX6DyrGDyf-G0BkCts5Ty2VpgG4UTAYwcB7ejFF24Ixui/exec';

var html = "<script>window.open('" + url + "');google.script.host.close();</script>";

var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open Tab');

}
```

BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK ON ANDROID :(

showModalDialog doesn't work on android :(

So I want to trigger my web app with a google script function (called with onEdit when selection in dropdown list changes to function name) that would open my web app which would prompt for user response ON ANDROID.

I thought that UrlFetchApp.fetch will do but no luck :(

So, in short: **LOOKING FOR PROMPT** in any form (as new page, sidebar menu or modal dialog) for user response that works **ON ANDROID**.

What I don't see?

Comment: The app versions don't have the same functionality. If you absolutely require something in the mobile app, then probably just print the link in a cell. Otherwise, open the spreadsheet in your browser and show the desktop site.

Comment: The features you want are currently only available for the desktop version of Google Sheets. There used to be android add-ons but those are now deprecated.